# Lowest OpenGL ES version to use Vertex Buffer Objects

Tags: android, opengl-es, vertex-buffer-objects

What is the lowest possible android and opengl es version that i can go and still be able to use vertex buffer objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertex Buffer Objects have been available in OpenGL ES since version 1.1.

ES 1.1 has been supported in Android since API Level 1 (see [GL11 documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL11.html)), which means that it has been in Android since version 1.0.